# print query values from session to view error Undefined index: DCM_TITLE

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, view, model

I'm new to CodeIgniter.

I have two functions in my Controller. In one with post method I create data array and then put that array to session. In another function I need another values, like title or date (because in session I only have ID values), so I send ID values to Model functions and then I load view with data I need. Then in view I print out the data I need. But I get an error saying

> Message: Undefined index: DCM_TITLE

**Controller function code:**

```php
 public function visi_registravimas(){
    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    $DCM_ID = $_SESSION['DCM_ID'];
    $PRD_ID = $_SESSION['PRD_ID'];
    $result['documents'] = $this->Skaitikliu_registras_model->setDocument($DCM_ID);
    $result['periods'] = $this->Skaitikliu_registras_model->setPeriod($PRD_ID);
    $this->load->view('skaitikliu_registras/visi_registravimas_view',$result);    
}
```

**model:**

```php
public function setDocument($DCM_ID){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM RA_DOCUMENT WHERE DCM_ID='$DCM_ID'");
    
    return $query;
}

public function setPeriod($PRD_ID){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM RA_PERIOD WHERE PRD_ID='$PRD_ID'");

    return $query;
}
```

And this is how I print data in **view**:

```php
<body>
    <?php $this->load->view('navbar_view'); ?>
    <?php foreach($documents as $document) : ?>
        <?php echo  $document['DCM_TITLE']; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this in Model Query:

```
return $query;

return $query->result_array();
```

**result_array()** returns the query result as a pure array Format.

Note:- For More Information regarding this

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the [@KUMAR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64374583/2055393) answer I would also advise to start using the query builder instead of writing the queries yourself.

This is a good practice so if in any case you change your database from MYSQL to postgresql or any other database engine you don't need to change anything about your models.

In this case your model functions would look like this:

```
public function setDocument($DCM_ID){
    $q = $this->db->where('DCM_ID', $DCM_ID)->get('RA_DOCUMENT');
    return $q->result_array();
}

public function setPeriod($PRD_ID){
    $q = $this->db->where('PRD_ID', $PRD_ID)->get('RA_PERIOD');
    return $q->result_array();
}
```

This way you get cleaner code and code that can be maintained for longer.